# UICollectionView cell reuse imageview will show error image which not belong to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

In cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
- (void)setupDeskWithLessonRole:(LessonRole *)role{
    [self initializeCell];
    if (role) {
        _stuPortrait.hidden = NO;
        _genderSign.hidden = NO;
        if (role.userInfo.gender.integerValue == UserGenderTypeMale) {
            [_stuPortrait sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:role.userInfo.portraitUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Student_por_boy"]];
        } else {
            [_stuPortrait sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:role.userInfo.portraitUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Student_por_girl"]];
        }
        _genderSign.image = [role.userInfo.gender intValue] == 0? [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lesson_boySign"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lesson_girlSign"];
        _name.text = role.userInfo.nickName;
        [_stuPortrait setBoardWidth:2 hexColor:[role.userInfo.gender intValue] == 0? @"4dc2ff":@"ff6683 "];
        if (role.isSpeaking) {
            [self startAnimation];
        } else {
            [self stopAnimation];
        }
        if (role.isRaisingHand){
            _raiseHandIcon.hidden = NO;
        } else {
            _raiseHandIcon.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
- (void)prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self initializeCell];
}
```

when reloadData the imageView in some cell which it's role is empty will show a image 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2PXo.jpg)

an the picture show,when the second role come in, I reload data and the second role's image will show in other cell's imageview

Answer (score 0):

You should set image everytime you reuse cell.